# SUM for all columns in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, sum

I have an SQL table with many columns(~200).

I want to create a LINQ query to obtain the sum of all rows by column. The result to be one row which represents the SUM of each column.

**How can be done this LINQ query?**

It's difficult to create a specific `.Sum(...)` for each column.

Comment: _"I have an SQL table with many columns(~200)"_ That's the problem. [Normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your table.

Comment: I can't. It's an old system that is in production. I need to build the application on the old database format.

Answer (score 3):

```
double sum = Table.Select(t => t.Amount ?? 0).Sum();
```

OR

```
double sum = Table.Sum(t => t.Amount ?? 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using:

```
var results = (from i in yourCollection
               group g by i.Column into g
               select new
               {
                   ColumnName = i.Column,
                   ColumnTotal = i.Sum(x => x.Value) 
               }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the right tool for the job. This time it isn't Entity Framework. Here is a simple ADO.NET routine:

```
public double[] SumAllColumns(IDbConnection connection)
{
    using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM YourTable";
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var values = new double[reader.FieldCount];
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    values[i] += reader.GetDouble(i);
                }
            }

            return values;
        }
    }
}
```

The method returns an array with the sum of each column.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sums = (from c in columns
    group c by c.columnName into g
    select new
    {
        SumCol1 = g.Sum(x => x.Col1), 
        SumCol2 = g.Sum(x => x.Col2) 
    }).SingleOrDefault;
```

To access the variables in a console application for example...

```
Console.Write(sums.SumCol1.ToString() + " : " + sums.SumCol2.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this solution:

```
from res in datacTx.Table
        where ...
        group re by re.id into g
        select new
        {
         col1 = g.Sum(x => x.col1),
         col2 = g.Sum(x => x.col2),
         ...
        };
```

but I can't access now any of the values or I can't convert the result into a list in which each column represent an entry in the list.

Until now I've used this, to access the values of linq query:

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in res.GetType().GetProperties())
{
 ...
}
```

but now this is not working because I don't have any properties.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a sqlcommand, which execution returns for each row a result array, then use array.Sum().

Or add a sql computed column.

Comment: array.Sum() is a linq to object method. There is no linq to sql method for columns.